# In .NET MAUI Custom DateTimePicker control Problem with "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'"

Tags: datepicker, initialization, instance, datetimepicker, maui

.NET MAUI Custom DateTimePicker control Problem

My Problem is that the InitializeComponent() has the error "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'"

Dongzhi Wang-MSFT came up with an elegant solution for a user to input a date and time into an entry.

His code adds a Date Picker and a Time picker below the Entry line, hiding the entry line until the Date/Time has been picked.  Genius!

I went through the steps to install it using MVVM.

My problem comes in where I've pasted this Partial Class into my MainPage.xaml.sc text (Where the Entry is to be made)

The InitializeComponent() code has the error "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'"

How and where do I make the Object Reference?

```
public partial class MyPicker : ContentView
{

    MyVM vm = new MyVM();

    public MyPicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = vm;
    }

    private async void OnEntryFocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {

        entry.IsVisible = false;
        pickerLayout.IsVisible = true;

        await Task.Run(() => WaitForChangedResult());

    }

    private async void OnPickerOKClicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        pickerLayout.IsVisible = false;
        entry.IsVisible = true;

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(vm.SelectedDateTimeString));

    }

    private void WaitForChangedResult() {

        while (pickerLayout.IsVisible)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked through the recommended Microsoft help and training links, but I cannot find where I went wrong, nor can I find a way or where to fix it, I can't see where or how to "first create an instance of the class ".

Any help would be appreciated.  I am, obviously, rather new to MAUI, but pretty good in C#.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable.  And please specify which line the exception occurs

Comment: The Code Problem is on Line 6  InitializeComponent();

Comment: again, please format your code.  It is completely unreadable as posted.  And please provide the stack trace for the exception

Comment: I tried, but the error from The Edit (and Original Posting) says "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."  I tried to paste it sensible, but it comes out all in a row.  (This is my first Question) The code is also visible on the original question. link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442084/net-maui-custom-datetimepicker-control-help

Comment: Please learn to use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).  This is a very common format and any professional developer should be familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and direction. I'm looking at how to use it now. (The CTRL+K I use in my code), Juist not sure how to get it into the Question so it makes a separate block, like I've seen on other questions.  I followed the prompts in the Question "wizard"

Comment: create a code block by indenting four spaces.  This is not complicated.  There are numerous tutorials on using Markdown

Comment: Try now, I think I got it.

Comment: Nope.  Please see my edit.  This is not difficult.  And you still haven't provided a stack trace

Comment: The program will not even start.  How can I get a stack trace (Call Stack)?

Comment: Please share the xaml of MyPicker, the issue is probably in there.

Comment: the stack trace is a property of the exception object.  If your code is throwing a runtime exception, then by definition it has been started

Comment: It is a build exception. (Red squiggly underlines appear in the code, prior to build)  The lines are under: InitializeComponent();  ,  pickerLayout.IsVisible = true; (under the word pickerLayout).  And a few other places in the code clock.  PS, thank you for the edit to the question, that is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.  I will learn.

Comment: a "red squiggly" is a compiler error, not a runtime exception.  Those are very different things and the terms you use when describing them matter a LOT.  If you had said "compiler error" when you posted this 24 hours ago I would have thought about it completely differently.  You also said, repeatedly, that the error was in `InitializeComponent` but now you are saying the "red squiggly" is on the line `pickerLayout.IsVisible = true;`.  It is almost impossible at this point to determine what the problem you are trying to solve is because of the number of contrary descriptions you've given

Comment: Suggestion: comment out all of the code except `InitalizeComponent` and build it.  Fix any errors, then incrementally re-introduce the rest of the code, fixing any errors as they appear

Comment: According to what you said, the error appears in InitializeComponent(); , pickerLayout.IsVisible = true; (under the word pickerLayout). You can check whether the MyPicker file you created is a file in .NET MAUI, and you can put your the Xaml code is also displayed to see if there are any errors.